# Aligning Div to the bottom right

Tags: html, css

I have two elements that I would like to put on the bottom right of the page.I went through a couple of threads but some parts help and others tend to kill the layout.

Note: The background color is for illustration purposes. I would like the text aligned to the right.

Here is where I am at: (http://jsfiddle.net/dsri/WswG9/)

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="a"> <span id="aa">Text1</span></div>
<div id="b"> <span id="bb">Text2</span></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#container{
text-align: center;    
}
span#aa{
font-size: 75px;
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
background-color: Yellow;
overflow: hidden;
}
span#bb{
font-size: 45px;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
background-color: red;   
}
```

This is what I would ideally like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYZQI.png

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WswG9/2/ like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the CSS for your `#container` div to:

```
div#container {
    text-align: right;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/WswG9/1/)**

Comment: Great..thanks for the solution. Though, I still can't get the alignment of the text right. For example, If I increase the text of "Text1" to 200, and "Text2" to 100 it throws the alignment off. Would applying "margin-right" be sensible ?

Comment: [HERE](http://imgur.com/pcf1lfl) is visual representation. The blue line indicates where I would like the text to align. I know I could use margin-right to do this but is there another way ?

Comment: That seems to be a result of the font more than the CSS like margins, padding, or letter spacing. I think you'd need to pull it to the side using a negative margin to align it the way you want.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. As an alternative, would it be sensible to remove the "container" div and target them manually ?

Comment: Just use a <p> element... <p style="text-align:right;margin-right:10px;"> Your Text Goes here </p> . This way you won't need to worry about positioning your Div absolutely etc..

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
div#container {
        text-align: right;
        position:fixed;
        right:0;
        bottom:0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/dsri/WswG9/   ?

```
div#container{

}

div#a,div#b{
text-align:right;
margin: 0 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This CSS

```
    div#container{
       text-align: right;
       position:absolute;
       right:0;
       bottom:0;   
    }
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/lvtrvd/Dzfpu/)